# Optimizing cumulative lift in classification

Tags: machine-learning, predictive-models, random-forest, unsupervised-learning, boosting

Suppose I have a business problem where I can reach out to 10% of my customers to prevent them from churning. I want to capture as much of the high risk customers I can. Let's say I'm tuning a random forest or GBM, then I can run a grid search and pick the model that has the highest (cross-validated) lift at the first decile. I'm wondering if there's a more direct/better way to achieve this.

(Equivalently, I think I want to maximize AUC at the left portion of the ROC)

Answer (score 1):

The best way to handle this is through selecting the # of trees that results in the best cross validated lift at a given percentile. Typically we choose the best iteration that minimizes the loss on cross validation splits.

So build the model in the same way as you typically would and then calculate the response rate at 10% depth of file for every iteration in your model. Choose the iteration that results in the highest response at 10%.

Edit: This is how Salford Predictive Modeler does it (Treenet) and this can easily be implemented in R or python. As far as I know, there is no method for maximizing AUC as the cost function to optimize. I think this would be very difficult to do.